# Bitcoin mining question about hashrate helping you exponentially

Tags: mining-theory, hashpower

I am a total newb in the crypto mining world and was researching the profitability of bitcoin mining when I came across bitclub which offers almost 4x more profit than mining by yourself. Their argument is that they have more hashpower so they make more bitcoins exponentially. Is that true? Do we make more bitcoins exponentially if we have more hashpower? If I were mining with a super computer, would I make exponentially more bitcoins or would it be the same as per 1H/s multiple by the hash power you have?

Answer (score 1):

That seems to good to be true and probably is a scam. The word 'exponentially' is being used with no regard to what it really means.

To mine 'exponentially' more coins you have to have 'exponentially' more hashpower.